# Identify tab within xul document opened inside a tab

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul

When one xul document (chrome://myextension/content/mydoc.xul) opened inside two tabs, is there a way assign an unique id to each tab, so it would persist on page refresh?

I'm using modules for easy communication between two tabs, and I need a way store data for each tab independently, which will persist when tab is refreshed.

P.S.
gBrowser is not accessible within content document of a tab(?)
Right now I'm using `window.name`, which works for my needs, but it's value accessible to any document opened in the same tab.

Comment: At this point in time it is unusual for someone to be asking about XUL in a Firefox add-on in a way which implies new development, as opposed to maintenance. Are you really working on a legacy add-on, or is this a WebExtension. If it's a WebExtension, you should avoid the use of XUL.

Comment: We're going to need more information as to *exactly* what you're doing in order to be able to determine what solutions might work for you.

Comment: Please keep your Questions to one question per Question. Questions which contain multiple questions which are not *very* tightly related are considered too broad and tend to be closed. The reason for this is that the Stack Overflow format is intended to provide a base of questions and answers which are useful to people in the future, not just the person currently asking. Questions with multiple issues tend to be too specific to be useful to others searching for help to their problems. Often, to solve a larger issue it is necessary to combine the answers from multiple questions.